# reading input file and summarizing data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on my assignment for my intro level computing class and i've come across an error that i am unable to understand as to why it occurs.

My goal (at the moment) is to be able to extract information from the input file and store it in such a way where i get 3 values-- animal id, time visited and station.

Here is the input file:

```
#Comments
a01:01-24-2011:s1
a03:01-24-2011:s2
a03:09-24-2011:s1
a03:10-23-2011:s1
a04:11-01-2011:s1
a04:11-02-2011:s2
a04:11-03-2011:s1
a04:01-01-2011:s1

a02:01-24-2011:s2
a03:02-02-2011:s2
a03:03-02-2011:s1
a02:04-19-2011:s2
a04:01-23-2011:s1
a04:02-17-2011:s1

#comments
a01:05-14-2011:s2
a02:06-11-2011:s2
a03:07-12-2011:s1
a01:08-19-2011:s1
a03:09-19-2011:s1
a03:10-19-2011:s2
a03:11-19-2011:s1
a03:12-19-2011:s2
a04:12-20-2011:s2
a04:12-21-2011:s2
a05:12-22-2011:s1
a04:12-23-2011:s2
a04:12-24-2011:s2
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import os.path

def main():
    station1={}
    station2={}
    record=()
    items=[]
    animal=[]


endofprogram =False
try:
    filename1=input("Enter name of input file >")
    infile=open(filename1,"r")
    filename2=input('Enter name of output file > ')
    while(os.path.isfile(filename2)):
        filename2=input("File Exists!Enter name again>")
        outfile=open(filename2.strip(),"w")
except IOError:
    print("File does not exist")
    endofprogram=True

if endofprogram==False:
    print ('Continuing program')
    records=reading(infile)
    print('records are > ',records)




def reading(usrinput):
    for line in usrinput:
        if (len(line) !=0) or (line[0]!='#'):
                AnimalID,Timestamp,StationID =line.split()
                record= (AnimalID, Timestamp, StationID)
                data=data.append(record)
                return data

main()
```

What i am trying to do us to open the file and import the 3 data sets seperated by a' : ' 
The error i keep recieving is as such:

```
Continuing programTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 25, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 34, in reading
builtins.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I have tried to switch the term in my reading function to :

```
AnimalID,Timestamp,StationID =line.split(':') ]
```

But still nothing.

Comment: just added it. but in short im trying to get those data values seperated by :   but im not getting anywhere with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `Comments` is a line in your file. So the first line that your `reading` function will try to parse is the line that is simply `Comments`. This will not work because `Comments` will not create a sequence that is three elements long when you split the line on white space:

```
AnimalID, Timestamp, StationID = line.split()  # won't work with headings
```

Thanks to the recent formatting of your input file, you *could* use the above approach if you filter which lines you try to split (that is to say, you ensure that the line you are splitting always has two colons, which would give you three elements). The following approach might illustrate an alternative method that you might use to stimulate thought:

```
for line in lines:  # from the open file
    if ':' in line.strip():  # for example; need to distinguish from station visits from headings somehow
        print(line.split(':'))  # you don't really want to print here, but you should figure out how to store this data
```

As I say in the comment, you won't really want to print the last line; you want to store it in some data structure. Further, you might find some better way to distinguish between lines with station visits and lines without. I'll leave these items for you to figure out, since I don't want to ruin the rest of the assignment for you.

Comment: `if ':' in line` is not enough. What if the line is: `# a:b:c`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `len(line) !=0` that is always `True`. To select non-blank lines that do not start with `#`, you could:

```
line = line.strip() # remove leading/trailing whitespace
if line and line[0] != '#': 
   fields = line.split(':') #NOTE: use ':' delimiter
   if len(fields) == 3:
      data.append(fields)
```